# Difference in number of digits required to express numbers in systems with a different base.

Tags: logarithms

The equation for the number of digits required to express some number (N) given some base (b) is the following

$\lceil{\log_{b}(N+1)}\rceil$

If we want to see the difference in number of digits required for varying bases then then our general formula would be

$\lceil{\log_{b_{1}}(N+1)}\rceil - \lceil{\log_{b_{2}}(N+1)}\rceil$

But I'm not sure how to solve this for some number in terms of N since they have different bases.

This is for a Computer Science algorithms class so approximate answers are fine.

Comment: "But I'm not sure how to solve this for some number in terms of N since they have different bases."  Not sure how to solve what?  So far as I can tell $\lceil{\log_{b_{1}}(N+1)}\rceil - \lceil{\log_{b_{2}}(N+1)}\rceil$ is the answer.  If it's not, what is your question?

Comment: The difference in the number of digits required. I just found the solution reading in my textbook so I'll answer my own question in a comment right now

Answer (score 2):

To convert from one logarithmic base to another we have the equation

$\log_b(N) = \log_a(N)/\log_a(b)$

Thus the size of the integer is always different by log_a(b) which is a constant.

Comment: You want :"differ by a factor of", not just "different by". Since $2^{10} \approx 10^3$ the base $2$ logarithm of $10$ is just over $3$ so numbers have just over $3$ times as many binary as decimal digits. +1 for answering your own question. You have asked several questions here. When you get answers that help you should upvote them, and accept one.

Comment: ahhhh, there's the difference that I was neglecting that I should have understood better. Thank you!